# Storing and Loading spaCy Documents Containing Word Vectors

Tags: spacy

I have a bunch of document that I want to process with spaCy.  As I am loading in a lg model, word vectors will be generated for each document processed.  I want to store all this information to disk so that I can retrieve it a later time.  The reason being I am performing pairwise similarity.

So here is what I am doing to save them

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp(my_text)
doc.to_disk(my_file)
```

And here is what I am doing to restore then

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
idoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(os.path.join(saved_docs, all_docs[i]))
jdoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(os.path.join(saved_docs, all_docs[j]))
print(idoc.similarity(jdoc))
```

This yields:

> ModelsWarning: [W007] The model you're using has no word vectors
> loaded, so the result of the Doc.similarity method will be based on
> the tagger, parser and NER, which may not give useful similarity
> judgements. This may happen if you're using one of the small models,
> e.g. `en_core_web_sm`, which don't ship with word vectors and only use
> context-sensitive tensors. You can always add your own word vectors,
> or use one of the larger models instead if available.

as if the word vectors did not survive the to_disk/from_disk process.

What is the proper way to persist this information?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, I don't know if it is the most efficient.  But apparently the `to_disk()` function wasn't working the way I wanted it to.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
doc = nlp(my_text)
doc.to_disk(my_doc_file)
doc.vocab.to_disk(my_doc_dir)
```

And

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
idoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(my_doc_i_file)
idoc.vocab.from_disk(my_doc_i_dir)
jdoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(my_doc_j_file)
jdoc.vocab.from_disk(my_doc_j_dir)
print(idoc.similarity(jdoc))
```

The word vectors (when present) are stored in the individual token objects, like doc[0].vector would give the word vectors for the first token.  Simply calling to_disk on the Doc object does not populate these word vectors.