# Save and load nlp results in spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I want to use SpaCy to analyze many small texts and I want to store the nlp results for further use to save processing time. I found code at [Storing and Loading spaCy Documents Containing Word Vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820459/storing-and-loading-spacy-documents-containing-word-vectors) but I get an error and I cannot find how to fix it. I am fairly new to python.

In the following code, I store the nlp results to a file and try to read it again. I can write the first file but I do not find the second file (vocab). I also get two errors: that `Doc` and `Vocab` are not defined.

Any idea to fix this or another method to achieve the same result is more than welcomed.

Thanks!

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp("He eats a green apple")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
            token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)

NLP_FName = "E:\\SaveTest.nlp"
doc.to_disk(NLP_FName)
Vocab_FName = "E:\\SaveTest.voc"
doc.vocab.to_disk(Vocab_FName)

#To read the data again:
idoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(NLP_FName)
idoc.vocab.from_disk(Vocab_FName)

for token in idoc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
            token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and I had a few minor issues which I fixed on the  code below.

Note that `SaveTest.nlp` is a binary file with your doc info and
`SaveTest.voc` is a folder with all the spacy model vocab information (vectors, strings among other).

Changes I made:

1. Import `Doc` class from `spacy.tokens`
2. Import `Vocab` class from `spacy.vocab`
3. Download `en_core_web_md` model using the following command:

```bash
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

Please note that spacy has multiple models for each language, and usually you have to download it first (typically `sm`, `md` and `lg` models). Read more about it [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models).

**Code:**

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.vocab import Vocab

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
doc = nlp("He eats a green apple")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
          token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)

NLP_FName = "E:\\SaveTest.nlp"
doc.to_disk(NLP_FName)
Vocab_FName = "E:\\SaveTest.voc"
doc.vocab.to_disk(Vocab_FName)

#To read the data again:
idoc = Doc(Vocab()).from_disk(NLP_FName)
idoc.vocab.from_disk(Vocab_FName)

for token in idoc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
          token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

Let me know if this is helpful to you, and if not, please add your error message to your original question so I can help.

Comment: Many Thanks! It works very well :)).

Answer (score 3):

The efficient way to do this is to use a `DocBin` instead: https://spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#docs

Example adapted from the docs (you can use `doc_bin.to/from_disk` instead of `to/from_bytes`):

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

doc_bin = DocBin()
texts = ["Some text", "Lots of texts...", "..."]
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts):
    doc_bin.add(doc)

bytes_data = doc_bin.to_bytes()

# Deserialize later, e.g. in a new process
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc_bin = DocBin().from_bytes(bytes_data)
docs = list(doc_bin.get_docs(nlp.vocab))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. A serious issue when tackling a new field is vocabulary ;). Serialization means something else for me.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot of getting an answer but I tried your code and it doesn't work for DocBins. I pasted my code below for the import part

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
from LanguageIdentifier import predict

import fitz
import glob
import os

from datetime import datetime

import logging

#English-Accuracy: en_core_web_trf
#French-Accuracy: fr_dep_news_trf
#German-Accuracy: de_dep_news_trf
#Multi Language-Accuracy: xx_sent_ud_sm

#DocBins
FRdoc_bin = DocBin (store_user_data=True,attrs=['ENT_TYPE','LEMMA','LIKE_EMAIL','LIKE_URL','LIKE_NUM','ORTH','POS'])
ENdoc_bin = DocBin (store_user_data=True,attrs=['ENT_TYPE','LEMMA','LIKE_EMAIL','LIKE_URL','LIKE_NUM','ORTH','POS'])
DEdoc_bin = DocBin (store_user_data=True,attrs=['ENT_TYPE','LEMMA','LIKE_EMAIL','LIKE_URL','LIKE_NUM','ORTH','POS'])
MULTIdoc_bin = DocBin (store_user_data=True,attrs=['ENT_TYPE','LEMMA','LIKE_EMAIL','LIKE_URL','LIKE_NUM','ORTH','POS'])


#NLP modules
frNLP = spacy.load('fr_dep_news_trf')
enNLP = spacy.load('en_core_web_trf') 
deNLP = spacy.load('de_dep_news_trf')
multiNLP = spacy.load('xx_sent_ud_sm')

ErroredFiles =[]

def processNLP(text):
    
    lang = predict(text) 
    if 'fr' in lang:
        doc = frNLP(text)
        FRdoc_bin.add(doc)
        return
    elif 'de' in lang:
        DEdoc_bin.add(deNLP(text))
        return
    elif 'en' in lang:        
        ENdoc_bin.add(enNLP(text))
        return
    else:
        MULTIdoc_bin.add(multiNLP(text))
        return


def get_text_from_pdf(Path):
    text = ''
    content = fitz.open(Path)
    for page in content:
        if page.number == 1:
            text = page.get_text()[212:]
        else:
            text = text + page.get_text()
    return text


FolderPath = r'C:\[Redacted]\DataSource\*\*.pdf'
PDFfiles = glob.glob(FolderPath)
counter = 0

for file in PDFfiles:    
    counter = counter +1
    try:
        textPDF = get_text_from_pdf(file)
        processNLP(textPDF)
        
    except Exception as e:        
        ErroredFiles.append(file)
        logging.error('Error with file '+ file)
        logging.error('Error message: '+ str(e))
        MULTIdoc_bin.add(multiNLP(textPDF))
    
    if(counter == 10):  #For testing purposes only
        break


CreatedModelPath = r'C:\[Redacted]\Results' + datetime.strftime(datetime.now(),"%Y%m%d%H%M%S") 
os.mkdir(CreatedModelPath)

FRdoc_bin.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\FRdocBin'+'.nlp')
FRdoc_bin.vocab.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\FRdocBin'+'.voc')


ENdoc_bin.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\ENdocBin'+'.nlp')
DEdoc_bin.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\DEdocBin'+'.nlp')
MULTIdoc_bin.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+'\MULTIdocBin'+'.nlp')
```

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\[Redacted]\ProcessingEngine.py", line 117, in <module>
    FRdoc_bin.vocab.to_disk(CreatedModelPath+r'\FRdocBin'+'.voc')

AttributeError: 'DocBin' object has no attribute 'vocab'
```